# Similar functionality to NumPy "accumulate" but on multiple arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, accumulate

I'm trying to find a fast way (preferably without the use of `for` loops) that mimics the following code:

```py
# a and b are arrays of the same length
# f is function of 3 scalar variables

res = np.zeros(len(a))
temp = 1

for i in range(len(a)):
    temp = f(temp, a[i], b[i])
    res[i] = temp
```

Note that the `temp` variable is updated with each iteration. This piece of code is very similar to the functionality that can be achieved with NumPy's accumulate mechanism. However, in my case there are several arrays that are used in the function `f`.

The function `f` can be something like

```py
def f(temp, a_scalar, b_scalar):
    return temp * a_scalar + b_scalar
```

Comment: Show your f function

Comment: For an arbitrary python function `f`, then there's no real way to make it fast, because python will have to run the interpreted function `f` on each iteration.  `numpy.ufunc`s can be accumulated quickly because they are implemented in C, so numpy doesn't have to do the loop in python.  If there is some specific function `f` you want to speed up, there might be a way to do it using a combination of `numpy` functions.  If not, and you still really need your code to go faster, look into writing it in C and calling it using `ctypes`.

Comment: @mrip. Another reason to use C or numba is that even for this trivial example, numerical stability is likely to be an issue. A cumulative product of just a few large numbers can really cause some scaling problems.

Answer (score 1):

As with most vectorization problems, you would have to work out the solution on a per-function basis. For the example that you present, notice that `res[i] = res[i - 1] * a[i] + b[i]` can be rewritten as the following sequence:

```
res[0] = a[0] + b[0]
res[1] = (a[0] + b[0]) * a[1] + b[1] = a[0] * a[1] + b[0] * a[1] + b[1]
res[2] = a[0] * a[1] * a[2] + b[0] * a[1] * a[2] + b[1] * a[2] + b[2]
...
res[n] = a[0] * ... * a[n] + b[0] * (a[1] * ... an]) + b[1] * (a[2] * ... * a[n]) + ... b[n-1] * a[n] + b[n]
```

These terms are the cumulative sum of the product of `cumprod(a[:n:-1])` and `b`. You can also think of the tail of the cumulative product of `a` as `cumprod(a) / cumprod(a[:n]`. So we have

```
res[n] = prod(a[:n]) + sum(prod(a[:n]) * b[:n] / cumprod(a[:n]))
```

Since this relation consists of products and quotients, we can separate it into

```
res[n] = cumprod(a)[n] * (1 + sum(b[:n] / cumprod(a[:n])))
```

The remaining recursive term can also be rewritten as a cumulative sum of cumulative products:

```
res[n] = cumprod(a)[n] * (1 + cumsum(b / cumprod(a))[n])
```

The recursion has now been separated into a series of accumulations supported by numpy.

**Warning**

Keep in mind that the separation will be much less numerically stable than the original formulation. If this is important, use the original recursion and compile with numba, or just write the code in C.

**Example**

```
np.random.seed(0xBEEF)
a = np.random.uniform(-2, 2, size=10)
b = np.random.uniform(-3, 3, size=10)
res = np.cumprod(a) * (1 + np.cumsum(b / np.cumprod(a)))
```

The original implementation in the question and the code shown here produce nearly identical results:

```
array([-0.04044657,  2.5090314 ,  0.66147071, -1.40795856,  0.93920848,
       -1.75817347, -4.45795915,  2.2258663 ,  2.38540097,  1.43741821])
```

The differences are miniscule, on the order of 1e-16 at most, caused by the loss of precision due to accumulation vs incremental updating.